# Android-app compatibility requirements

Tags: support, android-app

I can't install the android-app, according to Google play it isn't compatible with my Galaxy Ace DUOS [GT-S6802](http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphone/GT-S6802CWATGY) currently running Android 2.3.6. What are the exact requirements for the app? Google play only states version 1.6 as a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now the app requires a device running at least Android 4.0. This might change in the future but not for the current alpha or initial release.